# Why does Facebook login page is not opening in external browser for Android 11?

Tags: android, facebook

We have integrated Facebook login in our app from long time. Now Facebook is making this [webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews) change, that login page should open in external browser and for the SDK 8.2.0 is required and also they added some condition which needs to be satisfied.

Code:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"/>
```

Troubleshoot:

- I'm not setting this: LoginBehavior=WEB_VIEW_ONLY
- I have a latest chrome default browser in my Android 11 device
- I don't have facebook app installed
- This below, I checked docs, but not sure, what is required related to custom tabs

> Ensure that your app has configured support for Custom Tabs properly.
> (For more information on Custom Tabs, see the Custom Tabs
> documentation.) To test your configuration:

Tried below both option, but no luck!

> Option 1
> Ensure your app is using version 8.2.0 or later of the Facebook SDK for Android. If so, you should not need to make any modifications to your Android manifest. If you have any items referencing “CustomTabMainActivity” or “CustomTabActivity”, remove them.
>
> Option 2 Configure your Custom Tabs intent filter exactly following
> the instructions in the "Edit Your Resources and Manifest" step of the
> Facebook Login for Android - Quickstart.

Any other suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am also using the 8.2.0, now the app is lauching in the browser after click on the facebook buttom (i.e) same as the image in the custom tab of this doc. Is this is good enough to use the login with facebook in my app? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews or does they reject this as well?

Answer (score 3):

Android version 11 now requires to have query permissions in AndroidManifest.xml in order to open web urls in external browser. I'm not sure with this but its worth to try.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility).

Here is example manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
...
```